How do I convert an equirectangular image to a globe with labeled data
I have 2 data sources:

A .png equirectangular image of a celestial body
A .lyr file containing labels alongside coordinates for the celestial body

How do I:

Convert the png into a globe-like structure where I can zoom in/out and drag to scroll (basically like Google earth)
On the same globe, add the labels as different pins

